# Requests with status 400 (Bad request) doesn't pipe the correct body

Tags: node.js, iisnode, requestjs

`request 2.83.0
node 8.11
yarn 1.5.1
Operating System: Windows Server 2012 R2`

We're using request to power our proxy. It works well for all requests, and we're even transferring big files (400MB), all methods work and etc.

We create our options object like this:

```
let options = {
  method: req.method,
  url: url,
  headers: proxyHelper.getHeaders(req.headers)
};
// The auth header needed to make the request
options.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
```

And then send it to request.

```
request(options, (err, responseFromApi, body) => {
      logger.log("Body from API")
      logger.log(body)
  }).pipe(res);
```

The problem happens on requests that return "Bad Request" in the body, (status code 400). 
The logger loggs the correct body, but pipes the wrong body to the client. The client only receives

"Bad Request". Instead of a complete JSON object that contains the reason for the error.

We use iisnode (a plugin for IIS) to run Node. It works locally when we run iisnode, but when we deploy it, it doesn't work.

Any ideas? Is it request? Is it pipe? Is it iisnode?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of struggling and research and breaking down the the whole node app, it was in the end IIS that took the body and and replaced its content with the statusText...